# Injection into Console Application with the Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector for test purpose but pretty new on OOP. I am trying to create loosely couple classes. Here is the my scenario.

I have User repo and interface like this.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public void Add(Model.User user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:"+user.Name+"\n"+"SurName:"+user.SurName);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IUserRepository
{
    void Add(User user);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

My `TestInjectedClass` Class and interface are something like this which I am planning to use in Program Main.

```
public class TestInjectedClass : ITestInjectedClass
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public TestInjectedClass(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void UserRepoRun()
    {
        var user = new User() {Id = 1,Name = "ada",SurName = "stack"};
        _userRepository.Add(user);
    }
}
public interface ITestInjectedClass
{
    void UserRepoRun();
}
```

And My console program looks like this:

```
class Program 
{
    static ITestInjectedClass _testInjectedClass;
    private static IUserRepository _userRepository;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        _testInjectedClass= new TestInjectedClass(_userRepository);
        _testInjectedClass.UserRepoRun();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public Program()
    {                 
        Bootstrap.Start();
    }
```

}

BootStrap class here:

```
class Bootstrap
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ITestInjectedClass, TestInjectedClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        //container.Register<IUserRepository, TestInjectedClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        //container.Register<IUserContext, WinFormsUserContext>();
        container.Register<TestInjectedClass>();

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

My problem when I run program, I am getting a value exception on the `_userRepository` inside `TestInjectionClass`.
How can I properly inject `TestInjectionClass` and `UserRepository` to Main Program. Thanks

Comment: so how can I fix this .thankx

Comment: should I register all dependencies before th e run programme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make `Bootstrap.container` available in `Program.Main` and then use it to create instances of classes instead of directly calling their constructors directly:

```
_testInjectedClass = Bootstrap.container.GetInstance<ITestInjectedClass>();
```

Of course you will need to expose it in `Bootstrap` for that to work:

```
class Bootstrap
{
    public static Container container;

    public static void Start()
    {
        container = new Container();

        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ITestInjectedClass, TestInjectedClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        //container.Register<IUserRepository, TestInjectedClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        //container.Register<IUserContext, WinFormsUserContext>();
        container.Register<TestInjectedClass>();

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

And call `Bootstrap.Start` from `Program.Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Bootstrap.Start();

    _testInjectedClass = Bootstrap.container.GetInstance<ITestInjectedClass>();
    _testInjectedClass.UserRepoRun();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because you are calling your `Bootstrap` code in `Program` class instance constructor.

So, actually when you start your program the execution environment, is calling entry point method `Main`. And your instance constructor is never executed.

Try changing your entry point method `Main` and 'Bootstrap' class code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
     var container = new Container();
     Bootstrap.Start(container);
     _testInjectedClass = container.GetInstance<TestInjectedClass>();
     _testInjectedClass.UserRepoRun();

     Console.ReadLine();
}

class Bootstrap
{
    public static void Start(Container container)
    {
        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ITestInjectedClass, TestInjectedClass>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<TestInjectedClass>();

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a small tweak to your answer. It's better to resolve the main class directly from the container, instead of creating it manually and resolve its dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Please use SimpleInjector

Sample please refer

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/dependency-injection-using-simple-injector/