# dependency injection into a console app

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, autofac

We use Autofac to do some simple dependency injection in our web app. It's all configured and registered in classes that operate behind-the-scenes.  It makes injecting stuff in our project painless easy just like this:

```
//interface
public interface ISuperHereService
{ }

//class that uses the interface
public class SuperHeroFactory
{
    public ISuperHeroService SuperHeroService { get; }

    public SuperHeroFactory(ISuperHeroService superHeroService)
    {
       SuperHeroService = superHeroService;

       ...do all our stuff...
```

However now I had to create a separate project as a console app. My console app has a Main method.

I'm not at all sure how to inject an interface into the Main method.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Autofac DI container in Console app](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56197/autofac-di-container-in-console-app)

Comment: explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903082/injection-into-console-application-with-the-simple-injector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create and configure your container in `Main` (or in methods called from `Main`.) 
Then resolve an instance of `SuperHeroFactory` from the container and call whatever methods you need to.

Someone may object that you shouldn't resolve anything directly from the container. That's true, but `Main` is your composition root. It's where we're supposed to reference the container, so it's appropriate there.

Comment: I am doing this, but then my DI is not automatically available in a library that is referenced by the console app. ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. (This was over 5 years ago.) It's probably good to ask as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

No, don't do that in your `Main()` method; rather define a separate class which should take that `ISuperHeroService` instance and do necessary work. Then create an instance of that class in your `Main()` method and at the time instantiating you can perform the same DI likewise you are doing now.